# Where to put .config file when recompiling kernel?

Tags: kernel, make

I am following the steps here to rebuild a kernel on a VM: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

I have a .config file that I want to use to build it. Where should I put this .config file so that when I type make it uses that? The source I'm building from is linux-lts-utopic-3.16.0, and I'm using the debian folder in that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The`.config` file needs to be present in the base directory of a kernel source code which you are going to compile using `make` utility. Go to base directory and type `ls -a` the  `.config` file should be there (probably in `/usr/src/`).

This is a blog for compiling a kernel from source (not ubuntu specific). https://prashantchikhalkar.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/linux-kernel-compilation-from-source-to-running/

Answer (score 2):

If your source file in `/usr/src/linux` copy  `.config` file into `/usr/src/linux` and run `make oldconfig`  instead `make menuconfig` then run `make` to compile your kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I have two "linux" folders in /usr/src/. One of them is linux-headers-3.16.0-30, and the other is linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic. How do I tell which one is in use?

Comment: It's none of them, they are headers files. You can download any source tarball from kernel.org and extract them anywhere you like in /home directory and follow the above steps.

Comment: @user3475234 -  if you want to check which kernel is in use, just type uname -r  it'll give you your running kernel version. If you are trying to learn how to compile a kernel please do it in your /home folder not in /usr/src/